# Read excel file to python but time format has changed

Tags: python, pandas

when I read the excel file to python.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_excel('1.xlsx')
data
```

Some part of my time data uploaded successfully but the another part of time data has some problems. Problem is on these columns (in_time, call_time, process_in_time, out_time).

1. Why is this happened?
2. And how to handle and normalize this time data ?

[image: click here to see image]

Comment: Looks like it is printing microseconds.  It is possible that the first few have the microsecond field set to zero.  You could go through every cell and make sure it is in whole seconds before printing.  Remember that internally, the time is stored as a fraction of a day.

Comment: Please have a look here: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html. You could probably use the `dtype` parameter to "force" a certain dtype. If that doesn't work, you could also have a look at and use a `converter` for these columns.

Comment: Does `pd.to_datetime(data['in_time'])` work?

Comment: the original data is required to fully understand the problem

Comment: @TobiasMolenaar No it doesn't work

Comment: @mnikley How do I upload the data here?

Comment: @Turan_Aghayev since you cannot paste the raw xlsx data here, either convert it to csv and paste a row with the problematic format as raw-text, or upload the xlsx on some file hoster and share the link. Both options are not optimal though.

Comment: @mnikley please write your mail. I will send one part of data to your mail